# No such table error even though it can insert into 1 table and not the other

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Using c#, sqlite

My database consists of JobApplicantsDB(PK) and FamilyParticulars(FK). I went back to my code after a few weeks and the error "no such table came" out even though it worked as intended the last time.

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
  HResult=0x800007BF
  Message=SQL logic error
no such table: JobApplicantsDB
  Source=System.Data.SQLite
```

I have confirmed many times that the db file is placed inside C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\JobApplication\JobApplication\bin\Debug with the db file being type file not sqlite database. The problem is that even though the error comes up, the data still inserts into the JobApplicantsDB table but not the FamilyParticulars table (which is foreign key-ed to the aforementioned table). Did I miss out something I didn't spot? The MAX(P1ID) is inserted into the FamilyParticulars table for easier deletion later on.

```
    private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;

    private void SetConnection()
    {
        sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
            ("Data Source = C:/Users/Tim/source/repos/JobApplication/JobApplication/bin/Debug/JobApplicants;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
    }

    private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql_con.Close();
    }
    private void Submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    //save applicants' questionnaire
    {
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
                ("Data Source = JobApplicants;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
            sql_con.Open();
            string txtQueryP1 = "insert into JobApplicantsDB (P1PosApp, P1FTPT, P1Name, P1DOB) values " +
                "('" + PositionAppliedtxt.Text + "', '" + FTPTCB.Text + "', '" + Nametxt.Text + "', '" + DOBdateTimePicker.Text + "')";
            ExecuteQuery(txtQueryP1);

                sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
                    ("Data Source = JobApplicants;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
                sql_con.Open();
                string txtQueryMAX = "select MAX(P1ID) from JobApplicantsDB";
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(txtQueryMAX, sql_con);
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                string txtQueryP2b = "insert into FamilyParticulars(P2ID, P2FamName,P2FamRelationship,P2FamNationality,P2FamDOB,P2FamOccupation,P2FamCompany) values(" + id + ",'" + FamNametxt1.Text + "','" + FamRelationshipCB1.Text + "','" + FamNationalitytxt1.Text + "','" + FamDOBdateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + FamOcctxt1.Text + "', '" + FamCompanytxt1.Text + "')";
                    ExecuteQuery(txtQueryP2b);
}
```

Comment: on the 2nd time you you open your con with `Data Source = JobApplicants` shouldn't it be `Data Source = FamilyParticulars` and if that's not the case, are you able to do the query on that DB directly?

Comment: Your queries are vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteparametercollection.add?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0)

Comment: @styx JobApplicants is the database name. JobApplicantsDB and FamilyParticulars are both tables that are in the same database. Sorry for the confusion. I can query to the insert into the FamilyParticulars table if I comment out the "string txtQueryMAX", "SQLiteCommand cmd" and "int id" lines and just insert in my own values.

Comment: @Cid Yeap just haven't got to that point yet.

Answer (score 0):

The JobApplicants file and JobApplicants database in the release folder were at 0kb but could still save to the JobApplicants table, not the FamilyParticulars table. I was running the code in release instead of debug so it worked when I switched it to debug but I'm still not sure why I can insert data into 0kb files in the release folder.

Basically, check whether the solution configuration is running in release or debug I guess.